# The cyclotomic integer $p- \eta _i$ is not divisible by $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book "Fermat's Last Theorem" by Harold M. Edwards, he starts a construction of a cyclotomic integer by doing the following: he considers the $ep%$ cyclotomic integers $j-\eta _i$ $(j=1,...,p$ and $i=1,...,e)$. So he proceeds to choose one of those , such that it is not divisible by $p$. He justifies its existence by saying, for example, that $p-\eta _i$ is never divisible by $p$, "because its coefficients are not congruent modulo p". Why is this valid?.

NOTE: By $\eta _0$ he means $\eta _0=\alpha + \alpha ^{\gamma^{e}}+\alpha^{\gamma^{2e}}+...+\alpha ^{\gamma^{e(f-1)}} $, where $\alpha^{\lambda}=1$, $\gamma$ is a primitive root modulo $\lambda$ and $e$ divides $\lambda - 1$ ($f=\frac{\lambda -1}{e}$).
By $\eta _i$ he means changing $\alpha$ to $\alpha ^{\gamma ^e}$